# udev on Ubuntu not working for USB plug in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, ubuntu-14.04, udev

I am trying to do a "simple" task, run a script `/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh` when I plug in a specific USB device. 
I created `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-USBTesting.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/10-USBTesting.rules` because I wasn't sure about where should I put them.
For the content of these files I used all the following (one-by-one):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0304", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh"
ACTION==“add”, SUBSYSTEM==“usb_device”, SYSFS{idVendor}==“18a5”, SYSFS{idProduct}==“0304”, RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”
SYSFS{idVendor}==“18a5”, SYSFS{idProduct}==“0304”, RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”
ACTION==“add”, SUBSYSTEM==“usb_device”, RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”
ACTION==“add”, KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”
ATTRS{model}=="STORE N GO      ", ATTRS{vendor}=="Verbatim", RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0304", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh"
KERNEL=="*", RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”
```

And of course issued the infamous `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` and even restarted my Laptop "just in case" a couple of times.

The content of the `/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh` :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
set -u

echo $(date) Started >> /tmp/USBTesting.txt
echo $(date) Started >> /home/elemer/USBTesting.txt
```

Nothing complicated, just testing it at the moment. `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh` has been applied.
If I run `/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh` it does what it should.

I am really running out of ideas. Did anybody managed to get something similar working on an ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS ? Would like to hear the correct solution.

EDIT:
`RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”` this was in my udev rule `RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh"` this is the correct one An untrained eye (like mine) will not spot the difference. `“` and `"` are different. And it looks like it makes the difference.

My new udev rule looks like:
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="f88331611c905b", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh"` or

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5", ATTRS{serial}=="f88331611c905b", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Verbatim", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0304", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh"`   -- got these informations from `udevadm info -a -n sdc` -- might need to change `sdc` to your own.

Now my script gets fired but twice for every plugin.

EDIT 2:
It turns out I had to add `ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device"` to the rule, and now it executes only once. This is how my rule looks like now.

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5", ATTRS{serial}=="f88331611c905b", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Verbatim", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0304", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBTesting"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something similar, and it worked.
Are you running a VirtualBox by any chance? I had issues with getting the USB port to remain active, but the native machine Ubuntu 14.04 with 4.0.5+ kernel seems to work fine. My differences were dumbing down what you had to (60-usb.rules):

```
RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh”
```

I reused your script for printing to the /tmp/USBtesting.txt. In addition, the only extra command was:

```
$ sudo service udev restart
```

After doing this, the USBtesting.txt is written 6 times per plug in.
If you run you the script directly, does your USBtesting.txt file get called?

Comment: Sorry but what was the full content of 60-usb.rules ?
I don't seem to have that file on my PC.
It is a phisycal box not a Virtual.

Comment: My kernel version : 3.13.0-48-generic
If I run /usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh from terminal it does get called (extra lines are being added and timestamped)

Comment: I think I found the cause of the problem:
RUN+=“/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh” this was in my udev rule
RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh" this is the correct one
An untrained eye (like mine) will not spot the difference.
“ and " are different. And it looks like it makes the difference.

Comment: My udev rule gets fired now, but twice.
This is my udev rule 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5", ATTRS{serial}=="f88331611c905b", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Verbatim", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0304", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBTesting.sh"

Comment: The "60-usb.rules" file was created by me, for testing, and only has that single line in it. You mentioned that it works now, due to the quotes issue (probably from copy/paste), but prints twice. Have you tried adding back:    ACTION=="add",

Comment: the `ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",` solved it, it runs only once now.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, `sudo service udev restart` is critical:

The udev documentation everywhere *says* that udev monitors `/etc/udev/rules.d/` for changes, but this is *not* the case under this distro, so it needs to be restarted each time the rules are changed.

Had me stretching my hair all day! Thanks Crizzo !

My `/etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules`: (all one line)

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="Lattice_Lattice_FTUSB_Interface_Cable", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo blah > /var/log/test'"`

This just overwrite `/var/log/test` when that particular device was plugged in.